# What is and what is not replicated in a glassfish cluster with a mod_jk load balancer?

Tags: replication, cluster, glassfish

I have a Glassfish (3.1.2) cluster over 2 computers as nodes, with a mod_jk load balancer.

Are servlet instance variables replicated perfectly? If not, how do I make sure it is?

Are all actions, including method calls and disk writes, replicated perfectly? If not, how do I make sure they are?

These may seem like stupid questions, but I'm not seeking "load balancing" as much as I am seeking exact replication to enable future upgrading without any service interruption. How do I achieve this if it is not already the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is replicated is session state. Method calls and disk writes, definitely not. The user has a session with *one* member of the cluster, and that continues until it fails, in which case another cluster member takes over the session in the same state. It is assumed you are using a common, maybe clustered, database, LDAP, etc. The cluster members do not work in lockstep.